# How to fix parse error when stopping http-stream

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

The object of this is to download a -part- of an ongoing mp3 stream in node-webkit, a 'clip', so I have to be able to stop downloading at an arbitrary spot rather than consume a proper file.

First, I had to learn how nwjs downloaded streams, I found example code here:
http://sebastiandelgado.info/node-streams-for-node-webkit-apps/

I added lines 17 to 21, just as a test, to see if I could download an arbitrary number of bytes and play-back the file.

That worked, but I was getting a parse-error because on-data was still trying to write to a file-stream I had closed, so I added a flag on line 25 and that fixed the error.

The one remaining issue was stopping the http-stream, I needed to close the connection, so I did some more reading.

I looked at the docs for http.get() and was led to http.response():
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html

This, in turn, led me to incomingmessage:
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage

"...It implements the Readable Stream interface, as well as the following additional events, methods, and properties.
Event: 'close'#
function () { }..."

So I tried it on line 19.

That -did- work, the http connection stopped streaming, however, it also issued an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
events.js:125 Uncaught Error: Parse Error
```

The code works, the mp3 downloads and the http-stream stops, no detrimental effects...but I'd like to know how to fix the error.

I'm using nwjs 0.12.0 which uses the io.js fork of node.js, pleased with the results, so far.

```
NWEXE=path-to-nw.exe

01 function dlstream () 
02 {  
03 
04  var http = require('http');  
05  var fs   = require('fs');
06  var flag = true; 
07  
08  var req = http.get('http://streams1.kpfa.org:8000/kpfa_64', function(res) {
09         
10          var bytesDownloaded = 0;
11          var fileName        = 'Download.mp3';
12          var writeStream     = fs.createWriteStream(NWEXE + '/' + fileName);
13              
14          res.on('data', function(data) {
15                 
16              //test to arbitrarily end download/close http-stream
17              if(bytesDownloaded > (1024*16)){
18                 writeStream.end();        //close file stream
19                 req.close();              //close http connection
                   //ans: use req.destroy() instead of req.close()
20                 flag=false;               //set closed flag
21              }
22              bytesDownloaded += data.length;
23                 
24              //flag so we don't write to a closed file-stream
25              if(flag){
26                 writeStream.write(data);
27              }
28         });
29    });
30 }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer is instead of req.close(), I had to use req.destroy().

That stops a readable stream without throwing the error.